# Can't get any programs

Tags: unity, software-center

somehow I've lost my icon for starting the Ubuntu software Center and cannot install any programs or remove any programs.

Can you advise as to how to get one installed again? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with the icons on the left side of the desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Dash by clicking the icon at the top of Launcher (the left side bar) or by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> (the Windows key), then type **software center**.

You should see the Software Center icon, click it to open the Software Center. You can also drag and drop its icon to the Launcher to prevent searching every time you need it.

All installed software is accessible through the Dash, just type what you want and related items will show up. A list of all installed applications is shown when you click the **Applications** icon at the bottom of the Dash or press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. There's also a **Filter results** tool on the right to narrow the search results.